# JSF h:selectManyCheckbox inside ui:repeat via Map entry

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, dictionary

I faced with problem, when I put value as `String` into `List<String>` inside `<ui:repeat>`  when I press button I see that `List<String>` contains just records for last element of ui:repeat.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{util:toList(test.mapQestionsWithAnswers)}" var="entry">
                <h:inputHidden value="#{entry.key.questionId}" />
                <h:outputText value="#{entry.key.question}"
                    rendered="#{not empty entry.value}" />
                <p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{test.questionAnswerList}"
                    layout="pageDirection">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{entry.value}" var="ans"
                        itemValue="#{entry.key.questionId} #{ans.answer.answerId}"
                        itemLabel="${ans.answer.answer}" />
                </p:selectManyCheckbox>
            </ui:repeat>
```

Idea with `util:toList` from Baluscanswer [How to show hashmap values in jsf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001743/how-to-show-hashmap-values-in-jsf)

**//UPDATED**
I rewrite this code without using map

```
<ui:repeat value="${test.questionList}" var="question">
                <h:outputText value="#{question.question}"
                    rendered="#{not empty question}" />
                <p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{test.questionAnswerList}"
                    layout="pageDirection">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{question.questionAnswers}" var="ans"
                        itemValue="#{ans.questionAnswerIdentifer.questionId} #{ans.questionAnswerIdentifer.answerId}"
                        itemLabel="#{ans.answer.answer}" />
                </p:selectManyCheckbox>
            </ui:repeat>
```

But it doesn't help me I can get in `List<String>` just pairs question answer for last question in `<ui:repeat/>`. Seems as after every iteration questionAnswerList become empty

//Ok I read some article [Primefaces ManyCheckbox inside ui:repeat calls setter method only for last loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147440/primefaces-manycheckbox-inside-uirepeat-calls-setter-method-only-for-last-loop)

And I decide use map Map>

But in this part error `ClassCastException` String cannot be cast to List

```
public List<String> getQuestionAnswerList() {
    // return questionAnswerList;
    List<String> selectedQuestionAnswer = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (!selectedItems.isEmpty()) {
        Set<Long> idsSet = selectedItems.keySet();
        for(Long questionId : idsSet){              
            List<String> questionAnswerPair = selectedItems.get(questionId);
            selectedQuestionAnswer.addAll(questionAnswerPair);
        }
    }
    return selectedQuestionAnswer;
}
<p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{test.selectedItems[question.questionId]}"
                    layout="pageDirection">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{question.questionAnswers}" var="ans"
                        itemValue="#{ans.questionAnswerIdentifer.questionId} #{ans.questionAnswerIdentifer.answerId}"
                        itemLabel="#{ans.answer.answer}" />
                </p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

How I can get all choosen values in `List<String>`?

Comment: @Daniel Thanks but it doesn't help(

Comment: I mean't to say that you shouldn't use `$` in general... Not as an answer... You should create a map that will hold the selections per question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a map (call it `myMap` for example) where the key will be `entry.key` and value will be a list of the same type like `questionAnswerList`

something like

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{test.myMap[entry.key].questionAnswerList}"
    layout="pageDirection">
    <f:selectItems value="#{entry.value}" var="ans"
        itemValue="#{entry.key.questionId} #{ans.answer.answerId}"
        itemLabel="${ans.answer.answer}" />
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Comment: @Ok I try to do as you say but get other problem see above

Comment: @Ray instead of `itemValue="#{ans.questionAnswerIdentifer.questionId} #{ans.questionAnswerIdentifer.answerId}"` make the `itemValue` to be of a type which are present in the `questionAnswerList` type `<someType>` , cause right now `"#{ans.questionAnswerIdentifer.questionId} #{ans.questionAnswerIdentifer.answerId}"` is a string

Comment: This doesnt work for me. I get an array of objects and fails to cast to myObjectType. @Daniel do you know what else is missing from this example? i can facility my code through email or something. thank you

Comment: @allegjdm93, I suggest you to post a new question